# Browser Performance display/visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, xhtml

I am making a portfolio website and have a horizontal slider which will slide between each piece of work. Let's assume that there are 100 works and they are all graphically intensive and/or flash objects.

Let's also assume that there will be a maximum of 4 works on screen at any one time.

They are all in one large div which I manipulate with jQuery to modify the `left` property to move the `div`.

On a high end machine it works nice and smooth but on for example a netbook, it's really choppy... or even on a slower browser.

What I plan on doing is working out which works will be visible as they transition and show only them. I hope this will give a performance increase. However, I plan on setting the `visibility` property to `hidden` so the elements dimensions are still there. But, I am wondering would it be better performance wise to set the `display` to `none` and create a placeholder element instead of just hiding the work?

What other ways could I increase performance on slower machines/browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not gain any feelable performance increase from just making `display:none;`. The content will still be loaded.

Instead you could try to look at some ajax. An idea would be to preload 8 items even though you only show 4. Then at the users click on the "next"-button, the screen slides to the next 4 already loaded items and at the same time the next 4 items in the row will begin to load.

http://yensdesign.com/2008/12/how-to-load-content-via-ajax-in-jquery/

Comment: But eventually if the user slides all through the portfolio, all 100 items will be loaded... unless you suggest i delete elements after they are out of view then reload with ajax? which would be a hit on server performance

Comment: What you gain is much faster pageload time. When the user has 100 items on the page, the problem will be lagging when scrolling. There's nothing to do about that - unless as you mention, to remove earlier items.

Comment: It will not be as big a server performance requirement as you might think. The items will have id's #1 to #100, and it will just be removing the past four items. Nevertheless it is not very recommendable to have 100 grafical items to appear at the same page. An alternative to this could be to show 10 og 20 items and then have a "Show more"-botton when the user reach the end.